# Faster MongoDB bindings for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am sorry if my question tends to be a little personal, but I am sure there might be others who need this as well.

[Today I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317393/why-connecting-to-mongodb-from-node-js-is-slow/26318478) that `require('mongodb')` in my server-side script takes about half a second. Just to load. Not a big deal for a server software that is supposed to run 24/7. But to me as a developer this feels like a **compilation time**, which disrupts my comfortable development cycle.

I installed this official bindings package like this:

```
npm install mongodb
```

This is the [github repository](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) or maybe [this one](https://github.com/christkv/mongodb-legacy), not sure yet.

I think [this is the author website](http://christiankvalheim.com/) (Christian Kvalheim), maybe I could ask him, but I am used to the community support.

Thus is my question: *is* there another, faster/smaller/simpler implementation of MongoDB protocol for Node.js that is relatively full and more or less stable? I know that "alternative" questions are not welcome on StackOverflow, but in my situation I think it could be useful and might have a good answer.

Another part of my question is why it is so huge and takes so much time to load? Is not it just a "wrapper" to send simple commands to a server? All you need is just Http.connect and then connection.send(JSON.stringify()) or similar (bson?). Could this be done in a hundred(or whatever) lines even if you want to wrap each of the most common functions separately? I hope I just missing something.

```
find node_modules/mongodb/|grep .js|grep -v test|xargs -L1 cat|grep -c ""
```

Gives out

```
24151
```

Or maybe I just edit and rename my question to be "how official node.js mongodb package works and why it is so huge"?

Comment: Are you sure it's taking that long?  `require('mongodb')` takes around 100ms on my VM.  Fast enough to not be noticeable when developing.

Comment: the same here. It is almost instantaneous and I have never noticed anything on the orders of seconds.

Comment: Do you guys use Linux? I use Mint.

Comment: "how official node.js mongodb package works and why it is so huge". It works well, and is developed, tested and supported by the vendor of the database. For any serious project the latter alone is an argument to use it. You should take time to read the source code - there is a lot going on. The driver is replica set aware (a must for production environments),ssl and multi server ready, supports all auth mechanisms provided by MongoDB and whatnot. So much for the "huge" part. As for the slow part: Since you are using Linux, it should be easily possible to find out what slows you down.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.1 x64 on a VirtualBox VM.